# Keep HttpRequest stream open while I issue a Client.post

Tags: dart, dart-html

My dart server has a function which receives a POST request from a client.  I want to use information from that request to issue a POST to another server, then use the response from this other server to send a response back to the original client request.  When I issue my POST to the other server, it closes the stream on the inbound client request and I can no longer respond.  Is there a way to keep the request stream 'alive' while I do a POST? Or, is there another way to do this?  I did try to issue the POST on a different Isolate, but that didn't help, the http request stream is still getting closed.

```dart
void postRequest(HttpRequest request) async {
final endPoint = 'https://www.anotherserver.com/information';
final client = Client();

final data = request.headers.value('data'); // Get data from client
final response = client.post(endPoint, body: data); // Send data to other server

// Do stuff with the response from endPoint server

// For simplicity of this example, just send back the response body back to the client
// This write call to the request causes an "Stream Sink Closed" exception
// It appears the POST call to the endPoint server, caused the client request stream
// to get closed.
request.response.write(response.body);
await request.response.flush();
await request.response.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not `await`ing the client.post.... I need to do a better job of watching out for that.